# Mongojs: Ignoring Duplicate Objects Insertion

Tags: node.js, insert, duplicates, mongojs

I have this Node.js application that it gets a large sum of JSON data with unique ids and then inserts them into a MongoDB using Mongojs.

The problem is that in this large array of data, there might be some duplicate documents! so when using Mongojs to insert these data, it returns an error `E11000 duplicate key error` and wouldn't continue the insertion.

So what I'm looking for is something like the `continueOnError/keepGoing` option of native Mongo. It would ignore duplicates and continue the `insert`.
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#insert

This is my code if it helps:

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs'),
dburl = process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/test',
db = mongojs(dburl, ['concerts']);

function insertData(data) {
db.concerts.insert(data, {keepGoing: true, safe: true}, function(err, docs){
    console.log('err: ' + err + '  docs:' + docs);
    if(!err) console.log('data inserted successfully!\n');
});
}

exports.insertData = insertData;
```

Here in this code I have set option to true, but it still does not work (the same error).
Is there anyway that I can do this with Mongojs or do I have to use native-mongo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem, just in case.

```
db.concerts.insert(data, {continueOnError: true, safe: true}, function(err, docs){
       console.log('err: ' + err);
       if(!err) console.log('data inserted successfully!\n');
   });
```

**Source**: https://github.com/gett/mongojs/issues/58

Comment: But the param "docs" is always null. Do you have a solution to get all inserted objects?

Comment: I just tested again, when there is no error `docs` contains your data to be processed and in contrary when there is an error such as a `duplicate key`, `err` param contains the error message and document that has provoked this error. Hope this helps